# How to declare public var and return in controller mvc

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I have passed two arguments from view page to controller. but i dont know how to return this.."var Source". It should error show

[image]

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult FilterbyAutoComplete(string prefix,string filterBy)
    {
        VGLMSEntities2 db = new VGLMSEntities2();
        var Source="";
        if (filterBy == "Patient Name")
        {
            Source = db.Patient_Registeration.Where(m => m.PatientName.StartsWith(prefix)).Select(x => new { label = x.PatientName, val = x.PatientName }).ToList();
        }


        return Json(Source );
    }
```

Comment: Are you talking about the error shown in your screen shot?  Why do you have a screen shot at all?  It's not clear to me what the problem is here.

Comment: I coul'nt return this "Source".. Actually i have to write nested else if. i'm unable to return this object.

Answer (score 1):

`var` keyword is just a syntactic sugar, it doesn't really exists, it just tells the compiler to take whatever on the right and use it the same.

I believe you may want to use the type 'object' instead for that case.

You can also just do

```
    if (...)
        return db.Patient_Registeration....
return Json(); // In case condition didn't catch
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use dynamic

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult FilterbyAutoComplete(string prefix,string filterBy)
{
    VGLMSEntities2 db = new VGLMSEntities2();
    dynamic Source=null;
    if (filterBy == "Patient Name")
    {
        Source = db.Patient_Registeration.Where(m => m.PatientName.StartsWith(prefix)).Select(x => new { label = x.PatientName, val = x.PatientName }).ToList();
    }


    return Json(Source );
}
```